# PHP FuelSDK with Account: Unable to Auth

Tags: marketing-cloud, php

I am unable to get authenticated. I've copied/pasted the ID and secret.

Error that I am receiving is below:

Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\FuelSDK-PHP-master\vendor\salesforce-mc\fuel-sdk-php\src\ET_Client.php on line 243
Caught exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided.: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided, requestToken response:

Can anyone help me in this??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By considering provided Client ID and Client secret are correct, The one possible reason for this might be your IP address is not Whitelisted. Contact your admin to change "username and logins" settings under Security tab in Administration (Enterprise Level)